# Grab SELECTED text on UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview

How do I grab the SELECTED or HIGHLIGHTED text on a `UITextView`?  I already know how to do this on `UIWebView` using JavaScript.  Now I am trying to figure it out for the `UITextView`.

Answer (score 12):

you can do it by

```
NSRange range = [txtView selectedRange];
NSString *str = [txtView.text substringWithRange:range];
```

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3.0**

In Swift, getting the selected text from a `UITextView` is done by first getting the selected text range (a `UITextRange`), and then using that range to get the actual text:

```
if let textRange = myTextView.selectedTextRange {
    let selectedText = myTextView.text(in: textRange)
}
```